# Conditional selection of repeated measures from data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have data with repeat measurements on each subject (id) at a variable number of timepoints.  I would like to retain two row for each subject, timepoint == 0 and the timepoint closest to 4.  In the case rows with two candidate timepoints equally distant from 4, e.g. (3, 5), I want to chose the lowest (3).

As shown in the 'choice' column of the image below, rows with "x" would not be retained.

```
 dat <- structure(list(id = c(172507L, 172507L, 172507L, 172525L, 172525L, 
172525L, 172526L, 172526L, 172526L, 172527L, 172527L, 172527L, 
172527L, 172527L), timepoint = c(0L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

[image]

Comment: What's the logic for retaining `timepoint = 3` for the single instance of `id = 172528`, but discarding `timepoint = 5` for the single instance of `172529`, or `timepoint = 6` for the single instance of `172530` ?

Comment: I'm also confused. Why discard the single measurements for `id = 172529` and `id = 172530`?

Comment: I believe the data now matches the first two columns of the image, as intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could `arrange` by `id` and `timepoint` and for every group select the first occurrence when `timepoint == 0` and minimum absolute value between `4 - timepoint`. Since we have arranged it by `timepoint` `which.min` will select first `timepoint` with lower value (in case of tie).

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  arrange(id, timepoint) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(c(which.max(timepoint == 0), which.min(abs(4- timepoint))))

#     id timepoint
#   <int>     <int>
#1 172507         0
#2 172507         2
#3 172525         0
#4 172525         4
#5 172526         0
#6 172526         5
#7 172527         0
#8 172527         3
```

Comment: Nice one. Is there a cleaner argument to use than `which.max(timepoint == 0)`?

Comment: @cardinal40 What's "unclean" about `which.max(timepoint == 0)`? Very neat solution indeed +1.

Comment: @cardinal40 you could do `which(timepoint == 0)[1]` but that is definitely not any cleaner.

Comment: If you are sure that every ID has a time point of 0, you could replace it with 1 because you arranged the dataset. ```slice(c(1, which.min...)```

Comment: @Cole yes, excellent point but for that we also need to be sure that there are no negative numbers in `timepoint` column.

Comment: Good point. Another alternative which I put in my answer is ```match(TRUE, timepoint == 0)```. Or you could do ```first(which(timepoint == 0))```. Regardless, these aren't really clearer than ```which.max(timepoint == 0))```.

Answer (score 2):

Can you do something like this. Arranging by the distance and then the timepoint will put the smallest closest value first. Then you can use the `first()` function to grab the first value or filter for when the timepoint is zero.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  mutate(dist = abs(4-timepoint)) %>% 
  arrange(id, dist, timepoint) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(timepoint %in% c(0, first(timepoint))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(id, timepoint)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the `data.table` solution. It relies on the assumption that each ID will have a timepoint of 0. Otherwise, you should use `which.max(timepoint == 0)`. Credit to Ronak Shah for the which.min approach.

**Edit:** Changed to `match(TRUE, timepoint == 0)` and fixed an issue in base R approach.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(dat)

dt[order(timepoint),
 .SD[c(match(TRUE, timepoint == 0), which.min(abs(4- timepoint)))],
 by = id]
```

For kicks, here's base R:

```
do.call(rbind, by(dat[order(dat$timepoint), ], dat[order(dat$timepoint), ], function(x) x[c(match(TRUE, x$timepoint == 0), which.min(abs(4-x$timepoint))),]) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
zeros <- 
  dat %>% 
  filter(timepoint == 0) %>% 
  transmute(id, timepoint)

nonzeros <- 
  dat %>% 
  filter(timepoint != 0) %>% 
  mutate(diff = abs(timepoint - 4)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(diff == min(diff)) %>% 
  arrange(timepoint) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  transmute(id, timepoint)

df <-
  bind_rows(zeros, nonzeros) %>% 
  arrange(id, timepoint)
```

There is probably a way to do this in one pipe but I had an easier time visualizing what's going on this way.